# Extract Wikipedia JSON key php

Tags: php

How can I decode and echo the 'networth' `key-value` from this Wikipedia `JSON`.

```
<?php
    $json_string = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Jeff_Bezos&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&rvsection=0&format=json';
    $jsondata = file_get_contents($json_string);
    $obj = json_decode($jsondata,true);
?>
```

Comment: It would help if you explain in more detail the problem with the code that you've got so far?

Comment: The required "networth" is not a JSON Object. you have to do string find only.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work.

```
<?php
    $json_string = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Jeff_Bezos&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&rvsection=0&format=json';
    $jsondata = file_get_contents($json_string);
    $obj = json_decode($jsondata,true);
    $temp = $obj['query']['pages']['142528']['revisions'][0]['*'];
    $pos = strpos($temp, 'networth');
    for($x = $pos; ; $x++){
        if($temp[$x] == '=')
            $y = $x+1;
        if($temp[$x] == '}' && $temp[$x+1] == '}')
            break;
    }
    $networthValue = trim(substr($temp, $y, $x-$y)," ");
    print_r($networthValue);
?>
```